# retrySpeak property is not working in bot

Tags: botframework, bots

I have added retrySpeak property to builder.prompt.text incase if the user not responds for a while. But only the text in speak property will be spoken and not retrySpeak text. the below is the dialog which I am triggering from default dialog. I am testing this from cortana mobile app. Is there any property I missed here?

```
bot.dialog("mainServices", [
    function(session){

        builder.Prompts.text(session, 'How can I help you?', {            
    speak: 'How can I help you?',
    retrySpeak: 'How can I help you,please say something',
    inputHint: builder.InputHint.expectingInput
});

    }
])
.triggerAction({
    // The user can request this at any time.
    // Once triggered, it clears the stack and prompts the main services again.
    matches: /^start over$|^go back to main services$|^begin again$|start over services/i,
   confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your request. Are you sure?"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IPrompt Options retrySpeak](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.ipromptoptions.html#retryspeak)

This property is actually a re-prompt for if the response from the user was invalid, as opposed to a lack of response. For example, if speak prompted for a time (in my example a number), and the bot receives a string it cannot parse instead, retrySpeak is prompted asking for a valid message. This is where you can tell the user what input type you are expecting, or to enter a value within a set range, etc.

```js
bot.dialog("/", [
    function(session){
            builder.Prompts.number(session, 'Please enter a time for your reservation', {
                speak: 'Please enter a time, 1-4, for your reservation.',
                retryPrompt: 'That is not a number!', //what bot types
                retrySpeak: 'I\'m sorry. That is not a valid time. Please enter a time between 1:00 and 4:00', //what Cortana says
                inputHint: builder.InputHint.expectingInput
        });

    },
    function(session, results){
        console.log(results)
        session.endConversation();
    }
])
```

If you are particularly looking for a timeout check, take a look at this [botbuilder-timeout](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-timeout) package, which reprompts after a certain amount of time. Please keep in mind that it's a third party app and I haven't tested it myself. :)